# spresense IDEの設定＆デバッガについて

Tags: spresense

以下のURL先にVisual Studio Codeでデバッガ(LPC-Link2)を使うやり方を紹介しているのですがエラーが出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

デバッガ自体のLEDがついていないのと、エラーがtimeoutとあるので、
デバッガが認識していないような感じがするのですが、
デバイスマネージャーで見ると認識はしていそうです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Visual Studio Codeの設定
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ziI2fREZcE&feature=emb_logo
デバッガの設定
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=78&v=_Cu6uZSAEFE&feature=emb_logo

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

Visual Studio Codeでデバッガ(LPC-Link2)を使うやり方についてこちらで改めて確認いたしました。
お使いの環境条件によっては、ご指摘のtimeoutのエラーが発生することがあるようです。

**【問題となっている症状】**

Visual Studio Codeにてデバッガ接続時に
 　`Failed to launch OpenOCD GDB Server: Timeout.`のメッセージが出力される。

**【考えられる原因】**
　デバッガ起動時に稼働するOpenOCDのCMSIS-DAPコマンドにてCMD_INFOが失敗するとこのような
　timeoutが発生します。

原因はLPC-Link2に対するデバイスドライバーの問題と思われます。

**【前提条件】**

- LPC-LINK2基板へのCMSIS-DAP FWを焼いている。
- NXP社提供のLPC-LINK2ドライバのインストールをしている。
- SWDのコネクタを設けたSPRESENSEの拡張基板とLPC-Link2をコネクタで接続している。

以下の手順で解決ができる可能性が高いため、一度お試し願えますでしょうか？
　
**【対応方法】**
次の手順に従って、デバイスマネージャから該当するLPC-LINK2デバイスを一旦削除します。

1. 接続不能になったLPC-LINK2を接続した状態でデバイスマネージャーを開きます。
2. [表⽰] -> [デバイス(接続別)] に切り替えます。
3. LPC-LINK2が接続されている階層を開きます。
   (PC番号) -> ACPI x64 ベース PC -> Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System -> PCI Express ルート コンプレックス->Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0(Microsoft) -> USB ルート ハブ (USB 3.0) -> USB Composite Device
4. [CMSIS-DAP]で右クリックし、プロパティを開きます。
5. [イベント]タブの[情報]内の「デバイス USB\VID_1FC9&PID_0090&MI_00\6& (ここがID) &1&0000 が構成されました。」をコピーして、デバイスのIDを控えておきます。
6. LPC-LINK2を取り外し、再度デバイスマネージャーを開きます。
7. [表⽰] -> [⾮表⽰のデバイスの表⽰] にチェックします。
8. 3の⼿順で再度LPC-LINK2の階層を開きます。
9. 階層を開くと、半透明の[USB Composite Device]が複数出てきます。それを開いて[CMSIS-DAP]などが含まれているものを探します。
10. 4,5の⼿順でデバイスのIDを確認して、先ほど控えたLPC-LINK2のIDと⼀致するものを探します。(LPC-LINK2の個体ごとにドライバが割り当てられています)
11. 該当のデバイスが⾒つかりましたら、[CMSIS-DAP]の⼀つ上の階層の[USB Composite Device]上で右クリックして、 [デバイスのアンインストール] -> [アンインストール]で、アンインストールします。
12. アンインストールが終わりましたら、再度LPC-LINK2を接続して動作するか確認します。

上記対応でOpenOCDとICEとの接続が可能になれば、Visual Studio Codeでのデバッガの利用が可能になると思われます。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: 丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。
手順通り進めたのですが、状況変わらずです。
因みに子ウィンドウにはtimeoutとあるのですが、
デバックコンソールにはc:\msys64\opt\spresenseenv\usr\bin\openocdについて触れていて、自分のファイルを除くとspresenseenvの中にはsetupファイル1つしかありません。ここが問題だったりしないでしょうか？

Comment: 除くが誤変換でした。覗くです。

Comment: 原因はよくわからないですが、別途PCにinstallしているSWが
影響してtimeoutのエラーが発生していたようです。
該当のSWをアンインストールしたところ、無事ICEデバッグができました。